# Inject a NSString text to another UIViewController

Tags: ios, properties, uiviewcontroller, nsstring, code-injection

I'm trying to pass a `NSString` text to a `UIViewController` in button "click" event in iOS. I wrote following code.

```
self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

self.detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

self.detailViewController.urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
```

I've  already declared `urlAddress` property in `detailViewController`.
After I tested with `NSLog` in `viewWillAppear`, it shows only null values, not the `urlAddress` string. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the order of methods being called:

1. `initWithNibName`
2. `viewDidLoad`
3. `viewWillAppear`

Your string is changed only after all three have done their work.

Change your code to:

```
self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
self.detailViewController.urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
self.detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES]; //Triggers viewWillAppear eventually
```

Comment: viewDidLoad is actually called before viewWillAppear. viewDidLoad loads the view into memory, viewWillAppear is called right before it comes on screen.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the string after the view controller was already presented. Switch that and you should be good.